# background of a div not showing

Tags: css, image

I seem to be having issues getting the background of my DIV to show the background image.  I have the right path, as I have checked it online.  Is there something I am missing in the code?  All of the other background images on the site work fine, just this one seems to not work.

```css
footerBar {
    background-image: url(/images/art/footeremailbg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 68px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to style a `<div>`, but your CSS is looking for a `<footerBar>`.

Is `footerBar` the class of the `div`? If so, this should be:

```css
.footerBar {
  background-image: url(/images/art/footeremailbg.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 68px;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

if it's the `id` of the `div`, this should be:

```css
#footerBar {
  background-image: url(/images/art/footeremailbg.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 68px;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

footerBar have to define it as a class or an id to assign it to an item.

Class Example: `.footerBar`

Example ID: `#footerBar`

You then will you implement.

`<div class="footerBar"> </div>`